# Tridion - timeout error

Tags: tridion

Making changes to global publicaitons is giving time out error

```
database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_SYSTEM_GETBLUEPRINT".
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation
or the server is not responding.
```

Similarly CP is giving error

```
The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server
is not responding
A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure
"EDA_PUBLICATIONS_FINDBPCONFLICTS
```

Comment: When you have database performance problem, make sure that your database is optimized properly. So run whatever maintenance plans your DBMS has.

Answer (score 5):

As Frank mentions, the first step on any Tridion DB performance is optimization.
If you force a rebuild of Indexes and recompile the statistics, does the error still occur?
You can also recompile the statistics with the FULLSCAN option in SQL Server (or 100% sample size in Oracle) – this can help if your content is unevenly stored in folders / structure groups.

You can also simply increase the query timeout values in the Tridion Content Manager MMC snap-in (under “Timeout settings”).

You do not mention the version of Tridion (or the type of database), but if you are on Tridion 2011 GA HR1 you may want to look into hotfix CM_2011.0.1.75219.
This can be downloaded here (login required):
https://www.sdltridionworld.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2011/index.aspx

Note this hotfix is included in 2011 SP1.